# Stop CSS animation with jQuery if i use <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have two cards with back and front. But  in card TWO back, not work. Because i click animation work all time.

Need function for stop animation,if i use input string in card TWO? but works if i use card not input string!
Thx all who help =)

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
 });
```

```css
input.form,
button {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000;
}


.animation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.card-container{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 4%;
  background: #fff;
  
  /* Set the depth of the elements */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* Set the transition effects */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.card .back {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.formItem:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card .back label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: left;
}

.card .front {
  background: #000000;
}

.card .back {
  background: #8bc34a;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card-container:first-child .card .front {
  background: #000000;
}

.card-container:first-child .card .back {
  background: #8bc34a;
}

.cardTitle {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 4%;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
}

button.btnSend {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8bc34a;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
            <footer>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="wrapper-cards">
   <!--Cards ONE-->
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <h2>
                                        About 
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="back">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h3 class="cardTitle">
                                            Nice 
                                        </h3>
                                        <p>
                                           Thx for read this.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
       THIS PROBLEM <!--Cards TWO-->
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <h2>
                                        Contact Us!
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="back">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h3 class="cardTitle">
                                            Send a mail!
                                        </h3>
                                        <p>
                                            We wait letters from you.
                                        </p>
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="formItem">
                                                <label>
                                                    Name:
                                                </label>
                                                <input class="form" type="text" name="name" value="name" maxlenght="25" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="formItem">  
                                                <label>
                                                    Email:
                                                </label>
                                                <input class="form" type="text" name="mail" value="mail" maxlenght="35" /> 
                                            </div>
                                            <button class="btnSend">
                                                Send
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div> 

 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to check if there are focused elements in the card:

```
$('.card').click(function() {
  $(this).not(':has(:focus)').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  $(this).not(':has(:focus)').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
input.form,
button {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000;
}
.animation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 4%;
  background: #fff;
  /* Set the depth of the elements */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.card-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Set the transition effects */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .front,
.card .back {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.card .back {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.formItem:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.card .back label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: left;
}
.card .front {
  background: #000000;
}
.card .back {
  background: #8bc34a;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card-container:first-child .card .front {
  background: #000000;
}
.card-container:first-child .card .back {
  background: #8bc34a;
}
.cardTitle {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 4%;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
}
button.btnSend {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8bc34a;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper-cards">
        <!--Cards ONE-->
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
              <h2>About</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="content">
                <h3 class="cardTitle">Nice</h3>
                <p>
                  Thx for read this.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        THIS PROBLEM
        <!--Cards TWO-->
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
              <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="content">
                <h3 class="cardTitle">Send a mail!</h3>
                <p>
                  We wait letters from you.
                </p>
                <form>
                  <div class="formItem">
                    <label>
                      Name:
                    </label>
                    <input class="form" type="text" name="name" value="name" maxlenght="25" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="formItem">
                    <label>
                      Email:
                    </label>
                    <input class="form" type="text" name="mail" value="mail" maxlenght="35" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btnSend">
                    Send
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```